# "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.\r\nParameter name: index

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I currently studying web development using asp.net mvc5, now working on my school project. I would like to store and display image from database. I encountered this error.

[image: here is the screenshot]

Here is my code this is the controller:

```
public ActionResult AddItems()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddItems(FormCollection form)
{
    StoreItems i = new StoreItems();
    //i.ID = int.Parse(form["AlbumID"]);
    i.AlbumName = form["AlbumName"];
    i.Artist = form["AlbumArtist"];
    i.Genre = form["AlbumGenre"];
    i.DateReleased = DateTime.Parse(form["AlbumDateReleased"]);
    i.Price = int.Parse(form["AlbumPrice"]);
    i.Downloads = int.Parse(form["AlbumDownloads"]);
    i.Listens = int.Parse(form["AlbumListens"]);
    i.RecordLabel = form["RecordLabel"];
    HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[0];
    i.PicturePath = file.FileName.ToString();

    DAL.AddItems(i);
    return RedirectToAction("ItemLists");
}
```

And here is the model:

```
public static void AddItems(StoreItems i)
{

    byte[] bytes;
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(i.PicturePath))
    {
        string filename = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/default-artwork.png");
        bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);
    }

    else
    {
        string filename = i.PicturePath;
        bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename);


    }


    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DAL.cs);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(
        "INSERT INTO AlbumsTb ( AlbumName, Artist, Genre, DateReleased, Price, Downloads, Listens, RecordLabel, DateAdded, AlbumArt) VALUES( @AlbumName, @Artist, @Genre, @DateReleased, @Price, @Downloads, @Listens, @RecordLabel, @DateAdded, @AlbumArt)", con);
    //com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", i.ID);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlbumName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = i.AlbumName;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Artist", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = i.Artist;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Genre", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = i.Genre;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateReleased", SqlDbType.Date).Value = i.DateReleased;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Price",i.Price);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Downloads", i.Downloads);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Listens", i.Listens);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordLabel", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = i.RecordLabel;
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"DateAdded", DateTime.Now.ToString());

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AlbumArt", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = bytes;

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();

}
```

Comment: How are you posting file from client to the server ?

Comment: The issue behind this error is that the request does not have any file.

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya My thoughts exactly - that should probably be added as the answer.

Comment: Are you sure you are posting a file with the form. Provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce you problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no file posted with the request. Which means the array is empty. Hence the index out of range error. You should also practice defensive coding and check to make sure the array is populated. If the file is mandatory then you can gracefully error out and return relevant error message (BadRequest..etc)

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddItems(FormCollection form)
{
    StoreItems i = new StoreItems();
    //i.ID = int.Parse(form["AlbumID"]);
    i.AlbumName = form["AlbumName"];
    i.Artist = form["AlbumArtist"];
    i.Genre = form["AlbumGenre"];
    i.DateReleased = DateTime.Parse(form["AlbumDateReleased"]);
    i.Price = int.Parse(form["AlbumPrice"]);
    i.Downloads = int.Parse(form["AlbumDownloads"]);
    i.Listens = int.Parse(form["AlbumListens"]);
    i.RecordLabel = form["RecordLabel"];
    var files = Request.Files;
    if(files.Count > 0) {
        var file = files[0];
        i.PicturePath = file.FileName.ToString();
    } else {
        //...return some error code or validation message.
    }

    DAL.AddItems(i);
    return RedirectToAction("ItemLists");

}
```